# python: Assigning a list to a variable from a named list. How to avoid dependency?

Tags: python, list

I'm learning Python and just came across the following behaviour.

I define a list `x` and assign (what I think is) the values of `x` to the variable `y`.

```
>>> x = [1,2,3]
>>> y = x
>>> y.extend([4,5,6])
>>> print y
[1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6]
>>> print x
[1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6]
```

But after `extend`'ing the list `y`, both `x` and `y` has the extra three elements. The same goes for `append`.

```
>>> x = [1,2]
>>> y = x
>>> y.append(3)
>>> print y
[1, 2, 3]
>>> print x
[1, 2, 3]
```

I understood the assign operator `=` as assigning from right to left, what am I not getting?

How can I assign a list from a named list but still be able to alter the new list without affecting the old one? Or is this not the right way to handle lists in Python?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`y = x` assigns `y` to be the *same* list as `x`. Instead, you should copy the list. One way to do this is:

```
y = list(x)
```

Comment: Ok thanks. Does this only apply to lists? Because i tried adding something an int and it did not do the same thing.

Comment: In many programming languages, (including Python) this applies to objects, (like lists) but not primitives. (like ints) That is, you have to copy objects, but not primitives.

Comment: Ok good to know! Thanks.